# Python 3 BeautifulSoup get URL (href or baseURL) if div Class caption text contains "English"

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="gallery" data-tags="19 16 40193 41706 40476 7921 815 425 900 362 229 154 146 13 65 129 766 25 9 51931 188">
    <a href="/g/987654/" class="cover" style="padding:0 0 142.79999999999998% 0">
    <img is="lazyload-image" class="" width="250" height="357" data-src="https://abc.cloud.xyz/galleries/123456/thumb.jpg" alt="" src="https://abc.cloud.xyz/galleries/123456/thumb.jpg">
    <div class="caption">[User] Text ABCDEFGH [English] </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The Programm don't save the URLs/hrefs in to the txt file. I think that it can't find the href

If div element with class caption contains the Word English then the href (/g/987654/) of the beloging a element class cover should be saved in a txt file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://google.com"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

base_urls = []
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "caption"}):
    if "English" in div.text:
        a_tag = div.find_previous_sibling("a")
        if a_tag:
            base_urls.append(a_tag["baseURL"])

with open("base_urls.txt", "w") as f:
    for base_url in base_urls:
        f.write(base_url + "\n")
```

**What i tried so far
**
This Code works BUT it saves all the hrefs in to the txt file...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://google.com"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a")

hrefs = [link["href"] for link in links]

with open("links_test1.txt", "w") as file:
    for href in hrefs:
        file.write(href + "\n")
```

#######################################################################

**NEW PART**

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
   
    lurl = ["https://web.com/page1","https://web.com/page2","https://web.com/page3"]
       
for url in lurl:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    base_urls = []
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "caption"}):
    if "English" in div.text:
        a_tag = div.find_previous("a")
        if a_tag:
            base_urls.append(a_tag["href"])
with open("base_urls2.txt", "w") as f:
    for base_url in base_urls:
        f.write(base_url + "\n")
```

**It would be ideal if I could input a list or a txt file containing all the URLs. Any Idea??? For me trying to import a txt file in beautifulsoup was not possible...**
I'm pretty new to python...

***The txt file coul/would look like this***

https://web1.com
https.//user1.com
https://web.com

**Each line only 1 url**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the HTML snippet you should use `.find_previous` instead of `.find_previous_sibling`. Also, use `a_tag['href']`, not `a_tag['baseURL']`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<div class="gallery" data-tags="19 16 40193 41706 40476 7921 815 425 900 362 229 154 146 13 65 129 766 25 9 51931 188">
    <a href="/g/987654/" class="cover" style="padding:0 0 142.79999999999998% 0">
    <img is="lazyload-image" class="" width="250" height="357" data-src="https://abc.cloud.xyz/galleries/123456/thumb.jpg" alt="" src="https://abc.cloud.xyz/galleries/123456/thumb.jpg">
    <div class="caption">[User] Text ABCDEFGH [English] </div>
    </a>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")


base_urls = []
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "caption"}):
    if "English" in div.text:
        a_tag = div.find_previous("a")
        if a_tag:
            base_urls.append(a_tag["href"])

print(base_urls)
```

Prints:

```
['/g/987654/']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great ;-)

One more question...

Now I want to give the variable url a list instead of a single URL. I tied it but this error appeared, how can I fix it?

'''
InvalidSchema
No connection adapters were found for "['https://web1.com/page1', 'https://web1.com/page2', 'https://web1.com/page3']"
line 9, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
'''

Should I make a new thread/question post for that???

Comment: @Kirizu You're missing the `https://`. Try `base_urls.append('https://web1.com' + a_tag["href"])`

Comment: https is there but is not shown in the comment

Comment: @Kirizu Is `url` a list? then try to iterate over elements of this list and use `requests.get` on each element separately.

Comment: iterate over elements does not work for me... (See NewPart in the question Post)